# Unity timer not incrementing on level restart

Tags: unity-game-engine, time

something that I thought would be straightforward is proving to be difficult. I have a timer that tells me in seconds how long the game has been going on for and I want it to restart every time the game is restarted. here is the code i wrote.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int time= (int)Time.time;


    private void Start()
    {
        time = 0;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        time +=  (int) Time.time;

    }

}
```

when the game is first loaded it works fine, then when the game restarts when the player dies it seems to not move anymore and is stuck on the same value as it was from the match before.

Comment: Is this script attached to the `Player`?

Comment: no, this script isn't attached to an object. it should just play when the scene is loaded

Comment: How can this code gets executed if it is not attached to an object?

Comment: hmm i was under the impression that it would execute anyway... my bad, either way, attaching this script to an object does not increment time at all

Comment: `Time.time` holds the total time since the application was started. If you want to compute this value (so you can reset it, eg. a level timer) you should use `Time.deltaTime`

Comment: okay I will try that now, with the code above attached to an object I am getting crazy values like 88468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Default Time Variables**

Unity has some built-in Time variables that can do the same task.

For Example:

- Time.realtimeSinceStartup (It will give time in seconds since game is started)
- Time.timeSinceLevelLoad (Time in seconds since scene is loaded)

Ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html

**Custom Script:**

If you want to make your script to handle the time then there are few things you need to change:

- In Update function increment should be Time.deltaTime instead of Time.time. (Time.deltaTime will give time since last frame)
- Data type of time variable should be float otherwise converting Time.deltaTime to integer will always give zero.

  ```
  public class TimeManager : MonoBehaviour 
  {    
      public static float time = 0;

      void Start()
      {
          time = 0;
      }

      void Update()
      {
          time += Time.deltaTime;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just uploaded my answer as soon as you did.

Answer (score -1):

just an update for anyone who is having the same issue as me. i solved this issue with this code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int time=0;

    private void Start()
    {
        time = (int)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        time = (int)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
        Debug.Log("time" + time);
    }
}
```

this calculates the time since the level was loaded each time so when my player died and it restarts it begins counting up from 0